# React Redux chaining changes to reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

Suppose I have multiple reducers within my application that depend on one another. A single reducer handling an action may cause other reducers to also be updated and so on. What's the best way to handle this?

I'm assuming dispatching an action in a reducer is a bad idea. I could use redux-sagas to potentially handle this but it doesn't seem to make sense as what I'm trying to do here is not exactly a "side effect". All I need is for reducers to be triggered when the state of another reducer has changed.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Reducers are only update by actions. Reducer handles action by declaring its new state. You should improve your design.

Comment: If, when an action is dispatched that would result in a reducer modifying the state, then that same action can be picked up by any number of other reducers. Rather than the first reducer attempting to "call" another one (via an action) just have them handle the same dispatched action.